# Table structure for handling list of items

Tags: database

The following scenario is to be implemented in a Relational Database.

I have the following scenario:
There's multiple users, all unique. Each user can belong to 1 or more "teams". Each team can have an unknown amount of users.

So far i get that i should have a table with all the teams and another with all the users. 
But regarding on how to store the teams the user belongs to, do i need a field for each team id he belongs to? Do i also need to establish a limit of how many teams he can be in or can it be dynamic with a limit? (How to store a list, which in other applications the limitations are the memory available).

Ideally i would want a structure that would allow me to easily look up which Teams the user belongs to.

There's also a similar problem in the Teams table, do i also need to define a limit of users in the team? Do i need a column for each user in the team in that case?

Lastly, is this example something that should be avoided and i should be looking to struct it differently? If so please provide an example.

I'm not looking for code examples, only examples on how to build the relations in these.

Also accepting some recommendations for documentation that talks about which database struct types to use for each type of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is called many to many relation

your database should look like this

**Users** table contains (`Id`, `UserName`,`Password`,... other columns)

**Teams** table contains( `Id` , `Name`, .. other columns)

**UserTeams**( `UserId`, `TeamId`, other columns)

Now you have 2 options for table UserTeam

1. Both UserId and TeamId are primary and foreign keys: this means that each user cannot register in same team twice but can register in many but unique teams
2. Both UserId and TeamId are foreign keys and you have another primary key Id: this structure will allow you for example to track the history of user teams for example if you added date of join (required) and date of leave (optional) and you update it when the user leave the team and you need to add some constraints that the user cannot register in same team where the date of leave was null for both records of same user id and team id.

the second structure coding will be as follows:

**UserTeams**

- `Id`: primary key
- `UserId`: foreign key reference to `Users` table
- `TeamId`: foreign key reference to `Teams` table
- `DateOfJoin`: required datetime field
- `DateOfLeave`: optional datetime field , will be filled whenever the user leaves the team

Usually I prefer the second approach which can provide more details with less structure needed.

Hope this will help you

Comment: I really like your approach on that second case, i wasn't thinking that far but that actually fits what i had in mind really well!
I have a good idea of where to start now thanks to yours and Ghost's answers. Thank's a lot!

Comment: please accept my answer and vote up if you found it helpful

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. You will have a table for users, teams, and a table that joins them (UserTeam perhaps). The UserTeam table would store an ID for the user and a single team; if the person is on multiple teams, there would be multiple rows.

As far as limits, that is a requirements question and not a database question. You certainly can limit it, but should is not a technical question.

Here is the table structure in MS SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @User TABLE (
    UserID INT,
    UserName NVARCHAR(200)
)

DECLARE @Team TABLE(
    TeamID INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(200)
)

DECLARE @UserTeam TABLE (
    UserID INT,
    TeamID INT
)
```

Comment: So if the limit depends on the problem, if i assume that in 1 scenario a user could have anywhere from 1 to 1000 teams. Would it make sense to have a table purely for saving the list of teams each user belongs to?

So i would only store the id of the "list" in the user table, and not have to read through the 1000 teams if i ever wanted to read the entire row of 1 user.

Comment: Proper table design would be 1 user+1 team per row in a table separate from the user table or team table.

Comment: Do you mean that i would get rid of the "team" column under the user table. And instead i would have 1 table where each user would have multiple rows, with each row merely having 1 team. So if i wanted to find out which teams the user belonged to i would query that table for "X" user.


Also, is the reason for that because any database is optimized to add more rows constantly instead of columns? And also, doing that would give me better query time by sacrificing memory.

Comment: @Danyjex Updated my answer. The reason is that it is Normal Form.

Comment: Thank you, that structure makes a lot more sense now that i think about it! It helped a lot. Especially  at the extended example Hadi Hassan gave!